# Linux in Curriculum Vitae

Tags: software-industry, software-development

Open-source world is **weird** in some senses: it can create great stuff (e.g. entire working OSs) with thanks to the infinite people working on such projects but also *"glory"* goes to everybody and nobody at the same time.
Linux makes no difference (including applications and distros, or simply supporting them by bug squashing).

Question is: How can we recognize our work, our effort, in the open-source environment, for job purpose?
e.g. How can we include it in our CV?
Is there somebody who "officially" certify you (*knowledge*) and your work (*results*)?

Comment: If you are an active contributor to open-source projects, state that, and maybe even link to your e.g. github profile where potential employers can see your commit history.

Comment: If you have someone who "officially certify you (knowledge) and your work (results)" for non-open source project you can ask them about it... (I never heard of such thing so kind of surprised of the whole concept - to my knowledge one just write whatever they did/know and hope to prove that in conversations/interview). Clarifying what type of "official certification" you are thinking of may help with getting answers...

Comment: This question is difficult to answer because it's very broad. What type of contribution are you looking to highlight? I've seen people list open source repo maintainer under their Work History. I've also seen people list winning a bug bounty under Achievements.

Comment: There is no shortage of people and companies online who will certify you for almost anything if you pay them.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Broad questions get closed on this forum. What is your actual experience with Linux? Are you a user? a power user? an admin? a developer? What kind of developer? Also, what kind of job are you applying for?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere certification is a thing, for example Red Hat do certs. No idea if it's what OP is after though.

Answer (score 7):

If you feel that your contribution to a certain open source project is important and significant, you can add to your resume something like:

**Note**: be prepared to be asked about this project and your part in it.

**Education**

....

**Contributions to Open Source projects:**

- Wrote the internal engine of project X (+ relevant link)
- Developed the UI component Y of project Z (+ relevant link)

Comment: This is exactly what I've done on my CV. I've taken around 3 of my most interesting projects and listed them on my CV. And in most interviews I've been asked about some of them, so it's a good conversation starter at least. Plus some places want to see your code before you start, so there's your opportunity to get out of a take-home exercise.